# Automatically insert otp code from whatsapp

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an Android application in which I receive a text message via WhatsApp. I want that when I receive a message with an SMS code, my Android application will catch it and insert it into the field with the code. Is it possible to listen to the receipt of the desired SMS in WhatsApp?

Comment: This can be verified by referring to the documentation available on WhatsApp.